# Failed to load response data of css file

Tags: angular, angular-material

I wanted to try out Material Design in an Angular application, but I'm stuck with this error. I followed a guide on angular's website and tried to include one of the prebuilt themes.

This is my index.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>PDWS</title>
<base href="/">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" 
rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

The console prints this error:

[image]

Under Network, it looks like this:

[image]

The stylesheet is located in this folder:

```
C:\PDWS\node_modules\@angular\material\prebuilt-themes
```

Any idea what the problem is?

EDIT: My ngModule:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent
],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Create an `assets` folder in your `src` folder ( you might have it already). From `@angular/material` copy the `prebuilt-themes` folder. Create a `css` folder inside `assets`. Paste the copied `prebuilt-themes` in that `css` folder. Then in index.html, replace the statement with following `<link href="./assets/css/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the `..` in your link tag as the `index.html` is inside the `app` folder and you should go up a directory before going into the `node_modules` folder.

```
<link href="../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: I tried that first, but it gives me same same error.

Comment: @Jesper this is the only mistake I can spot for now from the limited code provided, so can you share your `ngModule` with us and double check your NPM installs?

Comment: I have added my ngModule. I guess I'm missing some import?

Comment: @Jesper no, you are not but are you using systemjs or webpack?

Comment: Webpack. The project is created with Angular CLI.

Comment: It looks like you are doing every thing right but the only remaining explanation of the failed get request is that the file is missing or the path is wrong. Try to rerun this command again `npm install --save @angular/material` and make sure you `cd` to your project folder.

Comment: Should i run it in the root folder of my project or in the src folder, or somewhere else?

Comment: in the root of your project where your `package.json` is located and then retry again!

Comment: Did what you said, but the result is the same unfortunately. My project is completely fresh. I didn't do anything except installing @angular/material and @angular/animations and then adding the imports to the ngModule if that's any help.

Comment: Try including `node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css` in `assets` object in `.angular-cli.json`.